# Encrypting SQLight Files without SEE in C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, encryption, sqlcipher

Ive been working on a C# Project that makes local copies of data in a SQLite File. These Files are rather large, with up to 20 million entries, at around 2.2GB. These Files contain sensitive Information and I cant just leave them unprotected.
For the last Week I tried to encrypt the files, but haven't gotten nowhere. Sadly i cant use SEE as my department doesn't want to spend 2k on the License, So i tried SQLCipher, but haven't really been able to get a good grip on that. I found a [tutorial](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/SQLCipher.html) that seemed promising at first, but i think it might not be possible to do with just the Community license, as i could not find the "SQLite.Interop.dll" that it told me to rename.

Any help with better understanding SQLite-Encryption, or any suggested tutorials would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why you dont use session storage instead , you can use js to encrypt it

Comment: @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ProtectedBrowserStorage;

Comment: @Ahmedaminshahin what makes you think this has anything to do with a *browser*?

Comment: i thought sql lite is used for browsers >.<

Comment: SQLite is a database. It does not depend on your browser. 
Have you tried something like this https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-ado/? 

Another option would be encrypt only your data instead of the whole database file.

Comment: @Ahmedaminshahin did you check the links you posted?

Comment: sry was out dated

Comment: Check the [Encryption docs on Microsoft.Data.Sqlite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/encryption?tabs=netcore-cli). As the doc says right from the start, `SQLite doesn't support encrypting database files by default.`. The $2K for SEE are essentially a "don't bother us" fee and even then there's no support for .NET - you still have to figure things out for yourself. The package mentioned in the tutorial is [actively maintained with the latest release 1 month ago](https://github.com/ericsink/SQLitePCL.raw)

Comment: @Ahmedaminshahin and cost $2K. That's the SEE version the OP is talking about

Comment: wait i will check something for you

Comment: If the backups cant be left unencrypted, it seems like the same would also be true of the active/production DB.  You can  encrypt SQLite DBs when you create them, then use the appropriate  connection string and encryption can be transparent to the app. AKAIR, it cant be layered on after the DB is created. Note: there  is a lot missing from the post such as what type of app this is.

Comment: Try using axcrypt

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp - Yes, the productive environment uses a comercial solution, so encrytion already comes with it. Regarding the Programm im writing, its a backround task that will run every 15 minutes and backup the entire database. (Old data once a day, and new data every 15 minuts) This data is then being copied to computers in the lab, where it will only be used in the case of a network problem, where the actual server is no longer accessible. The Data can then be accessed via a small client i wrote that allowes the data to be searched and printed.

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp - Regarding the Encryption of the SQLite-File, you said: "You can encrypt SQLite DBs when you create them", that would be perfect, as the File is created new every time, to completely eliminate every source of error. How exactly would i go about doing so? Could you refer me to a good tutorial?

Comment: @Ahmedaminshahin - As far as i can see axcrypt is just a Programm that encrypts the files, and makes it impossible to be used by my programm. That would require me to encrypt them before using them which would leave a plain-text file. I cant risk that somehow the programm fails to re-encrypt the file after it was closed, to whatever reason. The time it would take every time to decrypt the entire file is another problem.

Comment: download the opensource of axcrypt , you will know how to deal with it trust me

Comment: @Ahmedaminshahin - ok ill give it a try, thank you for your help

Comment: @SamuelSkorsetz if this goes well , i encourge you to think about making rest api where you can use api to encrypt these local copies and that will make you have your own encryption method not only for mysql but anything in the computer world . even the font you use to write letters :) .. don't forget to give me thumb :P

Comment: @SamuelSkorsetz in other words , you do not need to use any encryption method , you can always encrypt and decrypt using your API server , if you need help with that let me know which take less tham 1 seconds btw

Comment: @SamuelSkorsetz here is a link to start with
https://github.com/angeliquehuige/axcrypt-playground